# Passing a function as a parameter CPP

Tags: c++, function, class, arguments

I am attempting to call a class function in my main program that takes a function as its parameter, and applies the function to a private list. I am getting the error `invalid conversion from char to char (*f)(char)`. Hopefully I just don't understand how to pass functions as paremeters. The following are functions in my main cpp file

```
char ToUpper(char c)
{
char b='A';
for(char a='a';a<='z';a++)
{
   if(a==c)
  {
     c=b;
     break;
  }
  ++b;
}
return c;
}

void upperList(LineEditor line)
{
char c;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)   //ensure iterator is at beginning of line
  line.left();           

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  c=line.at();               //assign character current element pointed to by iterator
  line.apply(ToUpper(c));    //problem: trying to apply ToUpper function to char c
  line.right();              //apply function and increment iterator
}
}
```

And this is the apply member function

```
void LineEditor::apply(char (*f)(char c))
{
*it=f(c);
}
```

Also, in case it wasn't obvious, I tried using the cctypes toupper and tolower but they take and return integers.

Comment: ` I tried using the cctypes toupper and tolower but they take and return integers.` <-- `char` is implicitly convertable to `int`, or you can use `std::toupper`/`std::tolower`.  Your version of `ToUpper` is very inefficient.

Comment: Yeah haha with the code above it seemed to just throw implicit conversion out the window. With the code from answer though I have implemented these easily, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `ToUpper`, it doesn't return the function, it returns the (supposed) character in its uppercase form.

Another reason this doesn't work is because you cannot create arguments inside the signature of a function pointer. The area for the parameter only designates the type that the function takes. This...

```
char (*f)(char c);
//        ^^^^^^
```

is therefore wrong.

Solution:

Use a `std::function` and `std::bind` it to an argument:

```
#include <functional>

line.apply(std::bind(ToUpper, c));
```

It requires the signature of `apply` to be changed to:

```
void LineEditor::apply(std::function<char (char)> f);
```

If you can't do this, you can simply let `apply` take a second parameter as the argument:

```
void LineEditor::apply(char (*f)(char), char c);
```

and call it as `apply(ToUpper, c)`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `ToUpper(c)` calls the function, but when calling `apply` you don't want to call that function immediately, so you need do say `apply(ToUpper)`, since `ToUpper` is the way to access the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

the type of expression ToUpper(c) is char. So call

```
line.apply(ToUpper(c));
```

means to call function apply with argument of type char.

You should define the function as

```
void LineEditor::apply( char c, char f(char) )
{
*it=f(c);
}
```

Comment: you are not defining `it` anywhere in the `apply` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for you to reinvent the wheel.  `::toupper` and `::tolower` take and return `int`, but their valid range is that of `unsigned char`.  Additionally, `std::toupper` and `std::tolower` both take `char`.

Since it appears you are not using `std::string`, I'll try to keep it as close to your code as possible:

```
void upperList(LineEditor line)
{
    char c;
    // you do not have a begin() function??
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)   //ensure iterator is at beginning of line
        line.left();           

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        c=line.at();
        c = std::toupper(c);
        line.at() = c; // assuming this returns a reference
        line.right(); 
    }
}
```

It becomes much easier if you modify your string class to behave more like the `std::string` class:

```
std::string line;
std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), line.begin(), std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::toupper));
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/BMx15Y)

Comment: Original code was just a rough throwing together haha, added some better functionality and efficiency now :) Thank you for the reply!